# Angular universal not rendering async content

Tags: angular-universal

Angular Universal not rendering async content (like api calls) before page render. only leaves empty places like ""

already tried to copy all universal-starter configuration to an existing project but still same result.

i expect the page to render only after all http calls on the onInit function has ended , this is very important for seo matters

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem , it was one of the 3rd party lib that cause this problem (Cookies Service)